# Populate values from database to drop down in MVC C#

Tags: c#

I have country names in the table with the id for it as shown in image.I want to create a drop down in view page(HTML)using MVC model where the country names should populate in it using C# coding.

[image]

Comment: May be it would help if you can post what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to set up a property on your model that you can bind to a droplist. I put together a simple example using your data:

Create a class to represent your country tables:

```
public class country
{
    public string countries { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Now populate a list of the data from your table which you should be doing from a call to your database:

```
var countries = new List<country>();
countries.Add(new country() { id = 1, countries = "ind" });
countries.Add(new country() { id = 2, countries = "usa" });
countries.Add(new country() { id = 3, countries = "uk" });
countries.Add(new country() { id = 4, countries = "pak" });
countries.Add(new country() { id = 5, countries = "britan" });
```

There are multiple ways to bind your data but a simple method looks like this:

```
var countriesList = new List<SelectListItem>(
                countries.Select(_ => new SelectListItem() { 
                    Text = _.countries, 
                    Value = _.id.ToString() }
                )
            );
return View(countriesList);
// You can also add countriesList as a property on a bigger model
```

In your view, you'll want to bind the object you just created. In this scenario, it is simply the Model.

```
@Html.DropDownList("countries", Model)
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: i have already given id's in database in a table corresponding columns with id and country name and i want to retrieve them directly to dropdown with the help of id with out writing them again.can i do that?

Comment: view page is showing error near dropdown i dont know why?

Comment: What is the error? This exact code rendered a droplist in my test.

Comment: The class country in the model page is it  your model class ?